# jQuery tabs - Dynamic tabs with innerhtml possible?

Tags: jquery, tabs

i am trying to create a jquery tab control, by changing (populating) the innerhtml of a div tag with the correct html for a jQuery tab.

When the html page loads the first time, it displays the tabs correctly. (Obvoiusly the jquery css and html works)

When i click a button, to programatically change the innerhtml of the  tag, to load new content (tabs), the stylesheet does not seem to refresh and i am left with the new bulletpointed href tags displayed, instead of the tabs.

My question: Am i going about the right way of doing this (dynamically loading tabs) or is there a better way of doing this?  Should i just refresh the inline stylesheets somehow, to fix the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to do without an example, but Java_User is correct in using refresh assuming you're wanting to add a new tab.

If the HTML for the tabs is as follows:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Tab 2</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

A new tab can be added using the following code:

```
// number of existing tabs
var num_tabs = $("#tabs ul li").length + 1;
// add new tab
$("#tabs ul").append("<li><a href='#tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</a></li>");
// add tab content
$("#tabs").append("<div id='tab" + num_tabs + "'>#" + num_tabs + "</div>");
// refresh the content so they appear as 'tabs'
$("#tabs").tabs("refresh");
```

EDIT: Ignore the above. The only way I can get it to work is to destroy and recreate the tabs after injecting the new HTML. e.g:

```
// inject the HTML for the new tabs
$("#tabs").html("<ul><li><a href='#tabs-1'>New Tab 1</a></li><li><a href='#tabs-2'>New Tab 2</a></li></ul><div id='tabs-1'>New Tab 1</div><div id='tabs-2'>New Tab 2</div>");
// Destroy and recreate the tabs
$('#tabs').tabs('destroy').tabs();
```

Comment: i will give your suggestion a try. I am currently replacing the entire contents of <div id="tabs"> with new html (suitably formatted for jquery) and then calling the refresh method. 

Following is just a "scaled down" example of how i inject the Tabs.

ds = document.getElementById("tabs");
 
ds.innerHTML = "<ul><li><a></a></li></ul><div></div>";

$("#tabs").tabs("refresh");